# Is Windows 8.1 compatible with Apple MacBook Air MD711HN/A?

Tags: macbook-pro, windows

I'm planning to buy Apple MacBook Air MD711HN/A. I would like to know whether its compatible with Windows 8.1. Is it possible to have a single OS (Win 8)? I use Windows very frequently and travel a lot.

Comment: Although it is possible to fully remove OS X, as George says below, I would recommend against fully removing it. Keep it on a tiny partition if for nothing but firmware updates. And it wouldn't hurt to boot into OS X every now and then just to become familiar with the second most widely used OS. Who knows, you might like it!

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.** Boot Camp works with Windows 7 and above, including Windows 8.1. You can remove OS X and have a single partition for Windows, although you will not be able to do firmware updates.